# How to use Criteria And pagination

Tags: java, spring-boot, pagination, criteria

Hi guys I'm trying to use criteria along with pagination but my code isn't working, here it is :

```
public Page<Person> getAuthorizationsTest() {

    PageRequest pageRequest = new PageRequest(1, 5);

    CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Person> queryBase = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Person.class);
    Root<Person> root = queryBase.from(Person.class);
    List<Predicate> queryConditions = new ArrayList<>();

    Predicate predicate = criteriaBuilder.like(root.get("name"), "%[myValue]%");
    queryConditions.add(predicate);

    queryBase.where(queryConditions.toArray(new Predicate[]{}));

    TypedQuery<Person> query = em.createQuery(queryBase);

    List<Person> list = query.getResultList();

    Page<Person> authorizations = new PageImpl<Person>(list, pageRequest, list.size());

    return authorizations;
}
```

All seems fine, but when I execute it, I receive a list Page with all the results and not only the ones specified in my pageRequest

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 5):

Predicate array and where clause looking properly defined. In these lines:

> Predicate predicate = criteriaBuilder.like(root.get("name"),
>   "%[myValue]%");
>       queryConditions.add(predicate);
>
> ```
> queryBase.where(queryConditions.toArray(new Predicate[]{}));
>
> TypedQuery<Person> query = em.createQuery(queryBase);
> ```

Just a reminder. Maybe you need `criteriaBuilder.equal` instead of `criteriaBuilder.like`. If you sure what you did you can omitted this reminder.

You need to change following lines like:

```
query.setFirstResult(Math.toIntExact(pageRequest.getOffset()));
query.setMaxResults(pageRequest.getPageSize());

return new PageImpl<Person>(query.getResultList(), pageRequest, getTotalCount(criteriaBuilder, queryConditions));
```

Then add `getTotalCount` method for the sake of consistency.

```
private Long getTotalCount(CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder, Predicate[] predicateArray) {
        CriteriaQuery<Long> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Long.class);
        Root<T> root = criteriaQuery.from(entityType);

        criteriaQuery.select(criteriaBuilder.count(root));
        criteriaQuery.where(predicateArray);

        return entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery).getSingleResult();
    }
```

Comment: hi @gokhanbirincii I used your solution and now I'm having this error exatly on the `setFirstResult` and `setMaxResults`, this is the error:
    `java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended`
What could this be ? I'm using Oracle 10g just for you to know

Comment: are you sure pageRequest.getOffset() and pageRequest.getPageSize() not `Null` or `empty`. Can you send whole error log ?

Comment: Hi, it only works if I remove `query.setMaxResults(pageRequest.getPageSize());` otherwise it gives me the error `Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet] with root cause
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended...`
Tried changing my .properties to `hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect` but didn't work either, any ideas ?

Answer (score -1):

You are not using a paging request :

> List list = query.getResultList();

This query will always query for all the results which is very inefficient.

Instead, you should do this the ***Spring way*** ie you should use a repository interface that extends a `PagingAndSortingRepository` (such as the JpaRepository interface).

Then simply use a method to paginate your results such as findAll as stated in the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.definition-tuning) :

```
PagingAndSortingRepository<User, Long> repository = // … get access to a bean
Page<User> users = repository.findAll(new PageRequest(1, 20));
```

Comment: hey Laurent B thanks for helping, I showed a simplifiend version of my code, in reality it has many kinds of filters that may or may not be used, so refatoring my code to the "Spring Way" isn't an option in this case

Comment: Well Then use setFirstResult and setMaxResults as stated in gokhanbirincii's answer

Comment: Question specifically asked how to use Criteria.